# Why does echo -e "\n" give me two blank lines instead of one?

Tags: bash, text-processing, text-formatting

Let's say there's a line "aaaa" in file.txt, and I want to add ONLY ONE blank line after it, and then add a line of text after the blank line.
I did:
echo -e "\n" >> file.txt
echo "bbbb" >> file.txt
And then I saw TWO blank lines between aaaa and bbbb
When I use only echo "bbbb" >> file.txt then there's no blank line between the two text line.
Why does this happen, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: OK, let me summarise the correct answer: \n means to move the cursor to the next line and doesn't mean a blank line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo` outputs the string that you use as an argument, and then adds a newline character at the end of the outputted string to terminate the line.

With

```
echo "string"
```

you get `string`, and a newline at the end.

Therefore, with

```
echo -e "\n"
```

you will get your newline, and a newline at the end (i.e. two empty lines).

If you don't want the extra newline (i.e. to output an unterminated line), use `echo` with its `-n` option or, in this case where you just want to insert an empty line, just use `echo ""` or `echo` without an argument at all.

From `help echo` in `bash`:

```
Options:
  -n        do not append a newline
  -e        enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
```

If you want something that is portable to other shells besides `bash`, use `printf` instead:

```
printf '\n' >>file.txt
printf 'bbbb\n' >>file.txt
```

Or, another way of doing those two statements with a single redirection:

```
{
    printf '\n'
    printf 'bbbb\n'
} >>file.txt
```

Or simply

```
printf '\nbbbb\n' >>file.txt
```

Related:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Comment: If there's indeed a newline automatically added to the first line when I used echo, then why did I get no blank line between the text in my second attempt (described under my question)?

Comment: @OhLook In your first attempt, you add two newlines (one is your `\n`, the other comes from the newline that `echo` always adds). In your second attempt, you just add the string `bbbb` with a newline at the end. I don't really see where your confusion comes from.

Comment: I mean, if there's indeed a newline added to aaaa, then if I do echo "bbbb", there should be a blank line between aaaa and bbbb. But in fact there isn't.

Comment: @OhLook Why would there be a blank line? Your file would contain `aaaa\nbbbb\n` where the `aaaa\n` was there from the start and the `bbbb\n` was added by `echo 'bbbb'`.  Doing `echo -e '\n'` would add `\n\n` to the existing content of the file. If it contains `aaaa\n` already, you'll get `aaaa\n\n\n`.

Comment: But there's \n between aaaa and bbbb, why isn't a blank line shown?

Comment: @OhLook `\n` is a _newline character_.  It moves the cursor to the start of the next line.  Had there been no newline at the end of `aaaa` from the start, you would get `aaaabbbb` on a single line when appending `bbbb`.

Comment: If it just moves the cursor to the start of the next line, why are there two blank lines in my first attempt?

Comment: @OhLook `echo -e '\n'` adds two newlines. See previous comment. You would have a run of three newline characters in the file.  That means, the newline that is the end of the `aaaa` line (which was there from the start), and then two added by `echo -e '\n'`.  This makes for two empty lines.